# Is Bitcoin mining pools safe to invest with?

Tags: mining-pools

I happened to follow a few Bitcoin related profiles on Instagram today and within a few hours received about a dozen  messages from ppl asking if i wanted s fast secure return up to 5x my investment.  Of course i immediately assumed it was a scam then I did a Google search on.mining pools.  I haven't read where it's a scam or even a high risk move?

Can anyone give me advice on if I should even entertain the idea.  Or is it something that is just too good to be true.

Comment: Why should they ask you to give them money to 5x it, when they could 5x it their own? If they ask you via Twitter, I would not do it. There is a lot of scam. I think, buying a cryptocurrency and holding it for 1 year is a safer way to 5x your money...

Answer (score 1):

In general, get rich quick schemes are a scam.

Mining pools themselves are safe to mine with, but I do not know of any official investment schemes. Do not send your money.

Answer (score 1):

Like any good scam, typical mining scams rely on some element of truth, and separating the truth from the lie, especially in a technically complex field can be difficult.

Let me try to break it down piece-by-piece:

## Truths:

- Mining is a real thing.
- Mining in a pool is a real thing.
- Participating in a mining pool is possible
  If you bring your own ASIC miner and have cheap electricity.
- Investing in a mining pool is possible.
  It does not require your own hardware to mine.
  Some solicitations for mining investments are legitimate.

## Lies:

- **Fast returns!**
  Mining requires substantial upfront investment for hardware and other costs, then returns slow, steady profits over a long time. (assuming the Bitcoin price does not drop)
- **Guaranteed 5x return!**
  Mining does not have guaranteed returns, and certainly not 5x!
- **Risk Free!**
  Nothing is ever entirely risk-free, and if it truly is a sure-thing, then they would invest their own resources, and keep the risk-free profits for themselves.
- **We need your Bitcoin account / password / private key.**
  Mining requires expensive hardware, and lots of electricity, but does **not** need any of your Bitcoin info.